# Find strings that do not appear in a repository

Tags: unix, regex, grep, unix-utils, egrep

Problem: I have a moderately large repository (1000s of files, hundreds of thousands of lines).

I have a text file with ~5000 lines.

I need to find the lines in the text file that do NOT appear anywhere else in the repository.

Is there a tool, or a clever way to use grep, that can find this answer efficiently?

Thanks for any help

Comment: "I need to find the lines in the text file that do NOT appear anywhere else in the repository." Are we talking about entire lines or fragments in the repository? Let's say there is a line "foobar" in your text file and a line "foobar baz" in the repository. Is this an appearance? Or only the exact line "foobar" should be considered?

Comment: Fragments, the lines I am trying to match might be part of any line in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was developed in `bash` on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

---

#### The algorithm

This section is educational. You can find the whole script at the end of my answer.

First make a copy of your text file. This is important, the file we will work with will be overwritten and there's a reason for that. Adjust the variables to match your case:

```
patterns="/path/to/your/text/copy"
repository="/path/to/your/repository/"
```

You will need few temporary files.

```
tmpf1=`mktemp`
tmpf2=`mktemp`
```

The next command will store all (well, almost all, read along) patterns that appear in the repository to the first temporary file. See `man grep` to decipher the command. Also decide if you need to add the `-i` option to `grep`. The first `uniq` is optional, it is used to preliminarily reduce the data that goes to `sort`.

```
grep -rhoIFf "$patterns" "$repository" | uniq | sort | uniq | tee "$tmpf1" | wc -l
```

If the above command prints `0`, the `$patterns` file is your final result for sure, regardless of the pitfalls stated below, and you should only remove the temporary files.

There are pitfalls with `grep`, you will deal with them in a moment. It's good to know what they are.

1. If there are `foobar` and `foo` as patterns, `foobar` in the repository will match `foobar` only.
2. If there are `foobar` and `barbaz` as patterns, `foobarbaz` in the repository will match `foobar` only.
3. If there are `foobarbaz` and `bar` as patterns, `foobarbaz` in the repository will match `foobarbaz` only.

Because of these pitfalls `$tmpf1` may not contain all the patterns that really appear in the repository (i.e. it may not contain `barbaz` from the second pitfall).

Now you need to pick all those lines from `$patterns` that were allegedly not found in the repository. Note you need to match whole lines, hence `-x`.

```
grep -vxFf "$tmpf1" "$patterns" > "$tmpf2"
```

At this moment `$tmpf2` would be your final result, but because of those pitfalls it may contain too many lines (e.g. `barbaz` from the second pitfall). The trick is to use `$tmpf2` as a new pattern file and repeat the process! Invoke:

```
cp "$tmpf2" "$patterns"
```

then go to the first `grep`. Repeat this procedure until you get `0` from `wc` there. As I said before, when `0` is returned your result is in `$patterns`.

At the end remove the temporary files:

```
rm "$tmpf1" "$tmpf2"
```

---

#### Efficiency

I have 200k text files, 4.5M lines, 300 MiB total. These are HTML documents with simple headers and formatting, almost plain English text in body. I took 3k of most common English words as patterns and added few lines of mumbo jumbo.

First `grep` took few minutes to read the data from HDD and work, then about two minutes for `sort`. But every subsequent iteration was a matter of seconds thanks to the caching and to `$patterns` being reduced more and more.

My hardware is Core i7 and 8 GiB of RAM. Your patterns and files may be significantly different and influence your execution time. Nevertheless I think there's a chance you'll accomplish the task in several minutes.

---

#### The script

This is the implementation of the above algorithm. One additional feature is: it takes patterns from `stdin`, prints the result on `stdout`. In this case you don't have to copy your text file. The script is not foolproof.

Save the following code as `findUnused.sh`, then `chmod a+x findUnused.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

patterns=`mktemp`
cat > "$patterns"
repository="$1"
tmpf1=`mktemp`
tmpf2=`mktemp`

while [ `grep -rhoIFf "$patterns" "$repository" | uniq | sort | uniq | tee "$tmpf1" | wc -l` -ne 0 ]
do
  grep -vxFf "$tmpf1" "$patterns" > "$tmpf2"
  cp "$tmpf2" "$patterns"
done
cat "$patterns"
rm "$patterns" "$tmpf1" "$tmpf2"
```

Usage (note there are redirections):

```
./findUnused.sh "/path/to/your/repository/" < "/path/to/your/text/file" > "/path/to/store/the/result"
```